# Match string with regex

Tags: javascript, regex, photoshop-script

I need help with a Regex in JavaScript (for a Photoshop script) to match bold tags around words in a string. (not worried about italic or bolditalic at this time).
I don't want to split the string at this stage, I just want to chop it up into certain alternating chunks into using match.

```
// Be <b>bold!</b> Be fabulous!
```

Should get match to // ("Be ", "**bold!**",  "Be fabulous!") // line commented for obvious reasons

After that, I'll remove the bold tags - unless Regex can do that in one pass - don't underestimate it's power!

This is what I have so far

```
(.*?)([<b>]+[\S]+[<\/b>]+[\s]+)+(.*)/g
```

Only it doesn't match everything as [seen here](http://regex101.com/r/gW2mW0/1)

Just for the record, before anyone suggests a much easier JS solution:
In the Photoshop DOM you can't script regular text mixed with bold. You probably can with Action Manager code, but with generating text that could be a big headache.
To get around this (not an ideal solution) I'll be using regular text & splitting it up at the appropriate places & swapping to bold.

Comment: It seems that the link to regex101 is wrong

Comment: do you want to remove bold tag only?

Comment: Yup! I'm working on that :)

Comment: @user3218114 just now. Yes, just worried about bold tags for the moment

Comment: square brackets delimit a character class, not a group.

Answer (score 1):

`[<b>]` is character class, use simply `<b>` instead.

```
/(.*?)(<b>+\S+<\/b>+\s+)+(.*)/g
```

and change `\S` to `[^<]`

```
/(.*?)(<b>+[^<]+<\/b>+\s+)+(.*)/g
```

Comment: If that could work with multiple lines (including carriage returns) that would be a winner!

Comment: @GhoulFool: It sould work using the `m` modifier (multi-line mode). See http://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html

Comment: That's what I thought, but it doesn't catch all the text: [link](http://regex101.com/r/iQ9wG2/1)

Comment: @G: Try to remove the `(.*)` at the begining and at the end of the regex.

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
<b>(.*?)<\/b>
```

Here is [online demo](http://regex101.com/r/fV0eI5/1)

sample code:

```
var re = /<b>(.*?)<\/b>/gi;
var str = 'Be <b>bold!</b> Be fabulous! ';
var subst = '$1';

var result = str.replace(re, subst);
```

output:

```
Be bold! Be fabulous!
```

---

**Better** try with `String.split()` function:

```
var re = /\s*<\/?b>\s*/gi;
var str = 'Be <b>bold!</b> Be fabulous!';

console.log(str.split(re));
```

output:

```
["Be", "bold!", "Be fabulous!"]
```